# nested list in comp

Tags: prolog

I am trying to modify my list from [a, (a s b), ( a s b s c), a] to [[a], [a, b], [a,b,c], [a]]

I tried sth like that:

```
:- op(300, xfy, s).

lol([], List).
lol([X|T], List) :-
    X \=(A s B),
    lol(T, [[X]|List]).
lol([X s P|T], List) :-
    lol([P|T], [[X]|List]).
```

but this makes:

```
lol([], [[a], [b], [c], [d], [e]|_G4165]
```

Comment: We have to love your choice for the predicate name :-)

Comment: By the way, since you defined an operator, there is no reason not to use infix notation everywhere. You can write `X \= (_ s _)` or even just `X \= _ s _`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your base case is not correct as it leaves the tail of the constructed list unbound. It should be:

```
lol([], []).
```

The recursive cases can also be fixed as:

```
lol([X| Xs], [[X]| Tail]) :-
    X \= s(_, _),
    lol(Xs, Tail).

lol([X s P| Xs], [[X| Ps]| Tail]) :-
    lol([P| Xs], [Ps| Tail]).
```

With these changes we get:

```
?- lol([a, (a s b), ( a s b s c), a], List).
List = [[a], [a, b], [a, b, c], [a]] .
```

To avoid spurious choice points you can either add a cut in the first recursive case:

```
lol([X| Xs], [[X]| Tail]) :-
    X \= s(_, _),
    !,
    lol(Xs, Tail).
```

Or combine the two recursive cases using an *if-then-else* control construct (left as an exercise).